# Converting degrees and minutes to radians in prolog

Tags: prolog

Assume I have facts defined as follows,

```
airport(atl, 'Atlanta ', degmin(33,39 ), degmin(84,25 ) ).
```

and I want to convert `degmin` to radians. Here is my attempt:

```
toRadians(Source, LatRad, LongRad) :-
        airport(Source, _, degmin(X_1, Y_1 ), degmin(X_2, Y_2)),
        radians(X_1,Y_1,res),
        radians(X_2,Y_2,res2),
        LatRad is res, LongRad is res2.    
radians(Deg,Min,res) :- res is (Deg + Min/60).
```

However I get this when I run it.

```
?- toRadians(atl,Lat,Long).
false.
```

I am expecting something like

```
 ?- toRadians(atl,Lat,Long).
    Lat = some number
    Long = some number
    True.
```

What went wrong?

Comment: `res` and `res2` are literals, not variables.

Comment: what is a literal?. I know what a variable is.

Comment: Sorry, I meant atom. Basically they are exactly what they look like, they aren't able to hold any value. You need to use variables to represent the results of the calculations.

Comment: Ok, and what is an atom in this context?

Comment: `res` is exactly that: 'res'. Maybe the easiest (though not entirely accurate) way to interpret it is it being a string literal. So when you write `res is (Deg + Min/60)`, you are asking if the result of some numerical calculation can be unified with the literal string 'res', which obviously isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is your program corrected:

```
airport(atl, 'Atlanta ', degmin(33,39 ), degmin(84,25 ) ).

toRadians(Source, LatRad, LongRad) :-
        airport(Source, _, degmin(X_1, Y_1 ), degmin(X_2, Y_2)),
        radians(X_1,Y_1,Res),
        radians(X_2,Y_2,Res2),
        LatRad is Res, LongRad is Res2.    
radians(Deg,Min,Res) :- Res is (Deg + Min/60).

?-toRadians(atl,Lat,Long).
Lat = 33.65,
Long = 84.41666666666667
```

(I don't know if this is the value you want to obtain). Anyway, the problem comes from the fact that, for instance, you wrote `res` and not `Res` with capital R. This is important because in prolog variables **MUST** be written with a capital letter as the first letter, read [this](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse2).

Comment: To be complete, a variable may also begin with `_`, which would form an anonymous variable.